# How do I sort a randomized word in python for my hangman program (without it in alphabetical order and rather in its own order)?

Tags: sorting

In my hangman program, I am experiencing some difficulties in trying to organize the user's correctly guessed inputs (when they guess a letter correctly). For example, if the word was "frog", and the user guessed in the order "r", "o", "f", "g", the program should sort it (eventually) into "frog". When I do the .sort() function, it arranges it in alphabetical order (e.g. "fgor" for "frog"). Before using the .sort() method, I had no means of arranging it.

Here is a small piece of my code (pretending the word is "frog" which it isn't in my program):

word = "frog"
guess = input("Put in a letter") # with an iteration of a while loop

def hangman():
    nothing = []

```
points = 0

while num_of_lives >= 1:

    guess = input("Put in a letter: ")
    for i in word1:

        if guess in i:

            print(guess, "is one of the letters")
            points += 1

            nothing += i

            nothing2 = []

            for y in nothing[:]:

                nothing2[0:] += y[0:]

            nothing2.sort()

            print(nothing2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom sort method using this technique:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-sort/

```
# Python program to demonstrate sorting by user's 
# choice 

# function to return the second element of the 
# two elements passed as the parameter 
def sortSecond(val): 
    return val[1]  

# list1 to demonstrate the use of sorting  
# using using second key  
list1 = [(1, 2), (3, 3), (1, 1)] 

# sorts the array in ascending according to  
# second element 
list1.sort(key = sortSecond)  
print(list1)
```

You just need to create a function that returns the letter's position in the original word. This can be used to yield the key for comparison. For that I would look at pythons' `list.index`